# how to use buttons defined in one class that class inherits UINavigationController and appeared in every other class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c-protocol

is it possible that i define a class which inherit UINavigationController and add buttons in this class.and when ever i use this class in another class buttons will be shown on navigation bar of each class..hope it is clear.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UINavigationController, I would suggest you to subclass UIViewController and configure what ever you want in this class.

Further where ever you need the same implementation, just use your newly created class.

For eg; create new CustomViewController as below

in .h file

@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController {
}

in .m file,

-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

// Custom Implementation of bar and View as per your requirement
}

Now if you want to have this configuration in some other View Controller, subclass CustomViewController and everything will be done. Eg: If you have ListViewController,

in .h file,

@interface ListViewController : CustomViewController {
}

in .m file

-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad]; // Its super class is "CustomViewController" so viewDidLoad method you implemented in CustomViewController will be called and your view will be configured.

// Further Whatever you want in this controller
}

Hope it helps.